elastic search connection error while using it in flask API
I have a running elasticserver on Amazon linux having IP and port http://3.110.152.4:9200/,
but in flask its not connecting, in code its working fine, but in flask its giving connection error.
The code is:
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, jsonify
import time
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, ConnectionError
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
app = Flask(__name__)

# Initialize Sentence Transformer model
model = SentenceTransformer("all-mpnet-base-v2")

# Define the Elasticsearch connection function with retry logic

# Define the search function
def search_function(query):
    try:
        es = Elasticsearch('http://3.110.152.4:9200/')
        vector_of_input_keyword = model.encode(query)
        knn_query = {
            "field": "DescriptionVector",
            "query_vector": vector_of_input_keyword,
            "k": 10,
            "num_candidates": 100,
        }
        res = es.knn_search(index="house_6", knn=knn_query, source=["id", "price", "bedroom", "bathroom", "sqft", "builtArea", "location_name"])
        return res["hits"]["hits"]
    except ConnectionError as e:
        return {"error": str(e)}

# Define the Flask routes
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/search', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        query = request.form.get('query')
        if query:
            start_time = time.time()
            search_results = search_function(query)
            end_time = time.time()
            if "error" in search_results:
                return jsonify(search_results), 500
            return render_template('search_results.html', query=query, search_results=search_results, execution_time=end_time - start_time)
    return render_template('search.html')

# Run the Flask application
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
    #app.run(debug=True)


error is :
 elastic_transport.ConnectionError: Connection error caused by:  
 ConnectionError(Connection error caused by:  
 NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000273B99DC850>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061]  
 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it))

I tried that code but its giving connection error. In amazon security inbound rules, 9200,5000 all ports are allowed.
